# How can I toggle between multiple .css with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, toggle

Essentially I am trying to figure out how to expand the amount of things I can toggle between with a single button dynamically.  I am able to toggle between two of these with

```
<button type="button" id="spaceButton" onclick="$('#galaxy').toggle()">BRELLAS</button>
```

Which will toggle `#galaxy`, and my other background is an iframe with a video inside.

Basically, I want to be able to toggle between those two, and about 3 other css files, but I couldn't find anything suitable on google.

I'm very new to programming, please be gentle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, you can add/remove links to external css files, so in reality, you can toggle, well, everything. If you wanted to.

---

Edited to add example:

Given a link such as this:

```
<link id="cssLink" href="my.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The jQuery:

```
$('head')
    .find('#cssLink') // find your css link
    .remove()         // remove it
    .end()            // return to the $('head') object
    .append('<link id="cssLink" href="myNew.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">');
```

Comment: How do I go about actually doing it though?

Comment: I know I'm kinda pushing it, but how do I go about having it toggle through more css sheets?

Comment: Simply wash, rinse, and repeat :). (Put that in a function and call it as many times as you like)